# Lock mouse and keybord in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, winapi

Is there a way to block the mouse/keybord from .NET but System-wide? I tried with

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")> _
Public Shared Function BlockInput(ByVal block As Boolean) As Boolean
End Function
```

but it did not work.

I would like to avoid solutions like loading a driver, but I am open to that if needs be.

Edit: It did not work, because I stupidly did NOT run it with Administrator priviledges. So, the real question is how to block Ctrl-Alt-Del. Sorry for the mix-up and thank you for your answers!

Thank you,

John

Comment: BlockInput is pretty effective.  Of course it cannot disable Ctrl+Alt+Del.  "It did not work" isn't good enough to help you.

Comment: Could you add how it did not work?

Comment: BlockInput needs to be run in an elevated process on Vista/W7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fine-grained control you could set up [global hooks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804) for the [mouse](http://blog.bee-eee.com/2008/01/04/c-capture-the-mouse-get-a-global-hook-on-the-mouse/) and [keyboard](http://keymapper.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/keymapper/Classes/KeySniffer.cs) - WH_KEYBOARD_LL and WH_MOUSE_LL - then suppress the keystrokes and mouse movements by returning `(IntPtr)1` from the hook instead of calling [CallNextHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644974.aspx)